# Get ID of all deleted entities when parent is removed?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Lets say I have a Parent object that have several children with `cascadeType = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true`. Is it possible to collect everything that was deleted when the parent was removed?

If I log all sql queries I could see that multiple deletes is executed. But I no idea how to get all ids back.

Comment: Use something in the lines of this: `List<Entity> entities = repository.findAll().stream().filter(e -> e.getId().equals(parentId)).collect(Collectors.toList()); repository.deleteAll(entities);`. The `entities` will then just be the entities removed

Comment: There is several children of  the children also. So first finding them would not be the best solution (I think).

Comment: If you want to collect the ids of *all* deleted entities, including grandchildren, you could try using a `@PreRemove` listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @PreRemove which will be called whenever you try to remove an Entity.

I have used this for Audit purpose to keep track of Removed Records.

```
@Entity
public class Actor extends AbstractBusinessObject{

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "cast")
    private Set<Movie> movies;

    // setters and getters

    @PreRemove
    private void removeActorFromMovies() {
        //Executed before the entity manager remove operation is actually 
        // executed or cascaded. This call is synchronous with the remove operation.

    }

}
```